# How does Euler's totent function use p is not equal to q?

Tags: number-theory

I am writing a paper on RSA and introducing Euler's totent function. I wrote 
$\phi(n) = \phi(pq)= \phi(p) \times \phi(q) = (p - 1) \times (q -1)$ 
and my teacher said it is FALSE if p = q. He then asks how does it use p $\neq$ q ? I am not sure what he meant by that. But he provided examples such as
$\phi(27) \neq \phi(3)^{3}$ where $\phi(15) = \phi(3)\phi(5) = 2(4) = 8$. 
Can anyone please explain how does it use $p \neq q$?

Comment: If you want to know what your teacher meant, you might do better to ask your teacher, because only your teacher knows for sure.  In general, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ only when $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: $\phi (pq) = \phi(p) \phi (q)$ only if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Now do you see why it is not true if $p=q$?

Comment: $\phi(p^{k}) = \phi(p)p^{k-1}$

Comment: if $q=p$ then $\phi(p^2)=p^2-[1-1/p]$

Answer (score 1):

The totient is 'weakly multiplicative' which means that $\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)$ only if $\gcd(p,q)=1$.  It does not matter if p and q are composite, eg 14 and 15, just that gcd(p,q)=1.  If $q$ is a power of $p$ then $\phi(pq) = p\phi(q)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\times\phi(q)$ iff $\gcd(p,q)=1$

If $p=q$, the $\gcd(p,q)=p=q$.

Also, if $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $p\ne q$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's totient function is multiplicative but not fully multiplicative. If $\gcd(p, q) = 1$, then $\phi(pq) = \phi(p) \phi(q)$. But if $p = q$, then obviously $\gcd(p, q) = p = q$.

If $n$ is a power of prime, then the formula gets a little different: $\phi(p^\alpha) = (p - 1)p^{\alpha - 1}$.

But in some cases you can still take advantage of the other formula. For example, $\phi(63) = \phi(7) \phi(9)$; this works because $7$ and $9$ are coprime.